# Silverlight WCF databind related tables

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have a table with foreign keys. I want to display the data as the description and not the Id for the related table. From the Entity service I have made the `.Include` statement on the data model for it to return. Here is what I have tried, the station shows up in the cell, but nothing in the combobox:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" Width="Auto" Header="Station">
      <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Station.Description}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Station}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

 <OperationContract()>
  Public Function LoadPersonnel(clientId As Integer) As List(Of Personnel)
    Dim result As List(Of Personnel)
    Try
      result = db.Personnels.Include("Station").Where(Function(o) o.ClientId = clientId).ToList
    Catch
      result = Nothing
    End Try
    Return result
  End Function
```

Also tried:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Station.Description}" SelectedItem="{Binding Station.Description}" SelectedValue="{Binding Station.StationId}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this,

```
  <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="107,90,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="251" >
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" Width="Auto" Header="Station">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Station.Description}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Station}" DropDownOpened="ComboBox_DropDownOpened" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

in the drop down opened event, assign the itemssource,

```
 private void ComboBox_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var combo = (ComboBox)sender;
            combo.ItemsSource = Station;
            combo.DisplayMemberPath = "Description";
        }
```

Comment: Since Station did not exist, except as piggybacked data on the other datasource, I made an IEnumerable(Of Station) and filled it from the service. Now they populate with choices! I now need to get the selected value and apply that to the original object and save that back to the db via the service. I will play with that and see what I can come up with. I still need to figure out how to set the selectedItem to the correct value as well. If you have some insite into this I would love to hear, else I just keep plugging away...

Comment: To get selected value, var x = (Your itemssource object)combobox.SelectedItem;

Comment: Which event would you recommend? I have been looking at the events and they are so diff from Winforms and ASPX DataGrids(or similar). CellEditEnding looks promising. I normally would do that in the DataBound event.

Comment: BeginningEdit works great for getting me row dataItem. I just need to get the combobox from in here and set the selectedItem here. Tried:  Dim cbStation As ComboBox = TryCast(dgStaff.Columns(2).GetCellContent(e.Row), ComboBox) - did not work. Do I need to iterate the visual tree for it?